# Allow better formatting for comments

Tags: feature-request

when you write a longer comment to someone's question or answer you don't get any formatting options. A simple line break would make the comments a lot more readable.

Comment: What's the use case for this?  One reason that we don't have much formatting in comments is that they are currently overused, and we don't really want to encourage discussion in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are for quick notes about a post. If you need something more than that, there is the chat; you can create a room (if you have enough reputation) and leave a comment to the post, inviting the user to that room.

As HedgeMage said, comments are not for discussions; if two users start a discussion in comments, an automatic message offers to move the discussion on chat, and if one of the users click on the link, a chat room containing the copy of the comments is created.

Comment: sure, but sometimes you want to post a few lines in response or use a short code snippet. I understand the need to limit the comments, SE is doing a great job keeping everyone on focus ;-)

Comment: If you need to show a few-lines snippet, then a comment is not the proper place. It could be a sign that you need to add more details in the question, if you were the OP, or ask a new question.